# How to determine the convergence of a improper integral depending on its parameters?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

For example, I have this improper integral and I have to find for which values of $\alpha >0$ it converges and calculate I(3).

[image]

While I know how to calculate an improper integral, I'm not sure how to determine if it converges or not. Any help please?

Comment: Here's a hint. The discontinuity @ $x=1$ is removable for any $\alpha>0$

Comment: @MatthewPilling So does it means it converges for any value of $\alpha$ >0?

Comment: $\alpha>2$ I meant, sorry

Comment: Yes. Converges when $\alpha>2$ and diverges when $0 <\alpha \leq 2$. I'll leave it to you to explain why and to calculate $I(3)$. The easiest route in my opinion would be a $p-$ test comparison.